# Augmented reality android application

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make an android application that has "augmented reality" functionality in android application like start the camera and fill the colors virtually in real time. Please give me suggestion on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you search it in *Google*??

Answer (score 1):

http://bitstars.github.io/droidar/

look in here...
Should be good base for your future work

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of SDK's available today to integrate augmented reality in android application.

You will find the below mentioned links useful to choose SDK based on your app requirement. 
https://creator.zoho.com/reitmayr/augmented-reality-sdks/view-embed/AR_SDKs
http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks

If you want to go with a example, try the below
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-ar-android-app-with-vuforia-and-unity/